# Load Playbuzz embeded script into a WebView in Android

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I´m trying to load the content of a script of `Playbuzz` content inside a `WebView`

i found a way to do this loading an url of a web page containig the script:

```
String urlPlayBuzz = "http://www.jorgesys.com/playbuzzcontent.html";
webview.loadUrl(urlPlayBuzz);
```

[image]

---

but the requirement is load only the script and display the `playbuzz` content:

```
String script = "<center style=\"width:100%;\"><script> (function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='//embed.playbuzz.com/sdk.js' ;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}(document, 'script' , 'playbuzz-sdk' ));</script><div class=\"playbuzz\" data-id=\"9ed89fec-22cb-441e-b2a3-69b3bd1e6953\" data-show-info=\"false\" data-show-share=\"false\" style=\"width:100%;height:56.25vw\"></div></center>";
```

I have tried with this two options:

```
    webview.loadUrl(script);
```

and

```
    webview.loadData(script,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

with no success i only have an empty `WebView` as a result:

[image]

**How could i load the script of a playbuzz content and display it into the `WebView`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i´ve had found that my script contains relative paths like:

```
js.src='//embed.playbuzz.com/sdk.js'
```

Something different to embedded scripts of twitter or instagram that contains only absolute paths.

So i´ve used this method:

> [loadDataWithBaseURL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) Loads the given data into this WebView, using baseUrl as the base URL for the content. The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy. The historyUrl is used for the history entry..

You can define the base URL for the content:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://embed.playbuzz.com.com", url, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

now i can load content that contains scripts with relative paths!!!.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]